# How to set locale for errors.po?

Tags: phoenix-framework

How to set a locale in Phoenix, to get to use priv/gettext/{lang}/LC_MESSAGES/errors.po?

As a test, I built the locale file with `mix gettext.merge priv/gettext --locale ja`, and translated some words in it.

It works if I explicitly call `put_locale/2` in `web/views/error_helpers.ex` and `<%= translate_error(message) %>` in a template file, but it's a bit ugly, in a point of DRY.

```
def translate_error(msg) do
   Gettext.put_locale(LoginStudy.Gettext, "ja")
   Gettext.dgettext(LoginStudy.Gettext, "errors", msg)
end
```

Is there any better way to set the default locale? I specified the `default_locale` in `config/config.ex`, but it doesn't work.

```
config :login_study, LoginStudy.Endpoint, default_locale: "ja",
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great questions @hykw! Since Gettext support in Phoenix is new, documentation is just now starting to show up.

A good starting point is this excellent blog post by Rebecca Skinner: http://sevenseacat.net/2015/12/20/i18n-in-phoenix-apps.html

For example, if you want to set the locale to japanese only for some of your web requests, you can define a plug, as she did with `MyApp.Locale`, and run it at the beginning of your request lifecycle. I just don't advise to store the locale in the session but keep it rather as part of the URL or some other parameter.

However, if you want the locale to *always* be japanese, you can write in your config file:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Gettext, default_locale: "ja"
```

You can find more information about this on the Gettext docs:  http://hexdocs.pm/gettext/Gettext.html

Comment: José, thank you for the url and config!  It works perfectly!